# Automatic single sign-on for multiple providers

Tags: sso

Our company's customers can use our IdP to sign-in into about a dozen various service providers we make available. All are third parties running their own sites/domains. We periodically get complaints that signing into Service A doesn't automatically get you a client session on Service B (customers need to actually visit Service B and click 'log in').

I was hoping to get an idea on how I could politely tell them why this is a bad idea, assuming it's even possible with some hacky iFrames making a bunch SAML POSTs to grab a dozen session cookies that would likely never get used. Doing something so hacky with our security ecosystem just doesn't pass the smell test but I'm struggling to provide a good explanation.

Comment: I'm not sure if I really understand the expectation of the customer here. Do they really expect to get a client session on service B when logging into A, or do the just expect that they don't need to explicitly log in into service B once they've logged into service A, i.e. single sign on without any interaction as long as they are also authorized to use all these services.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich I think your second example explains it well from their perspective. They're simply confused why they're seeing a "Log in" link on Service B after they've already authenticated to Service A. Granted, all they have to do is click the that link to be automatically signed in (due to their active IdP session).